# Copying a file to a directory that might not be writable by the application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, unix, privileges

I am writing an application and I am at this point at the workflow:

```
-File A doesn't exist?
 -Copy file B to file A
  -Error?
   -Copy file B to file A with higher privileges
```

The problem is in the `Copy file B to file A with higher privileges' step. I am new to asking the admin for his/her password. I'd like a window similar to this, where the admin can enter the password so the file can be copied to an otherwise unwritable location:

[image: fix your image loading...]

I have totally no idea where to start, can someone help me out? Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

can you use AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges()

See [here for an example](http://michaelobrien.info/blog/2009/07/authorizationexecutewithprivileges-a-simple-example/) and [here for the full code to 'OSXSlightlyBetterAuth'](http://github.com/notbrien/OSXSlightlyBetterAuth).